# Rails 3 "scoped" value (scope vs class method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, class-method

I would like to know, why `scoped` value is different in case of `scope` keyword and a class method

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :first_scope, -> { where( "1=1" ) } # to be used by both 

   scope :my_scope, -> { p "S: #{ scoped.to_sql }"; where( "2=2" ) }

   def my_scope_2
     p "S: #{ scoped.to_sql }"; 
     where( "2=2" )   
   end

end
```

And testing what is it going to print out:

```
A.first_scope.my_scope     # "S: SELECT * FROM `A`"
A.first_scope.my_scope_2   # "S: SELECT * FROM `A` WHERE (1=1)
```

Although they produce the same relation object in the end: `SELECT * FROM A WHERE (1=1) AND (2=2)`, the intermediate scoped object is NOT(?) correct for `scope` definition

Is that expected behaviour?

rails 3.2.21; ruby 2.1.5p273

Comment: For what it's worth, in rails 4.1 they produce the same output (changing scoped to all since scoped was removed)

Comment: @FrederickCheung but you think it's a bug? As it is claimed to be identical.